# Does United Airlines have a smart suitcase ban that also bans those with removable batteries?

Tags: hand-luggage, united-airlines, tsa, domestic-travel

I have a Raden A22 carry on bag, and I'm flying on United. The Raden site says it is TSA-approved, and it has a removable battery. Have there been any new rules besides the ones affecting suitcases with fixed batteries?

Comment: Please clarify which rules you're referring to?